# How to open emacsclient with working directory set to $PWD?

Tags: emacsclient, eval

In my XTerm, I want to open new Emacs frame as well as buffer, with working directory set to $PWD in XTerm env.

I tried `emacsclient -t -c --eval "(cd $PWD)"`, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a buffer for a new file `./new-buffer` in the current directory, just call `emacsclient` with that filename, like

```
emacsclient -t ./new-buffer
```

The option `-t` causes `emacsclient` to open the buffer in a newly created frame on the current terminal.

If you create a new non-file buffer the default directory for that buffer is the current directory of `emacsclient`.

Examples:

```
emacsclient -t --eval "(eshell t)"
emacsclient -t --eval "(switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer \"*new-buffer*\"))"
```